# Signing APK multiple times

Tags: android, code-signing-certificate

I already know that Google Play Store does not allow APK signed more than once. When Android Studio builds an app, it spits out three variants-

1. app-debug.apk APK signed with debug key
2. app-debug-unaligned.apk APK
       signed with debug key but unaligned (not zip aligned)
3. app-release-unsigned.apk

When I try to use jarsigned on app-debug.apk, i got the following error:

> jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid
>   entry compressed size (expected 30138 but got 30879 bytes

However, I can use jarsigned twice on app-release-unsigned.apk in order to have two signatures on the APK. But the first approach (signing an APK after it's signed by Android Studio build process) does not work?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I think the question is obvious. Why jarsigner fails for an APK signed by build and several jarsigner commands pass for unsigned APK?

Comment: It doesn't seem very obvious to me. First you say you can't sign an APK twice, then you state that you want to sign an APK twice. You are getting that error because you are trying to sign an APK twice. So...if your question is how to sign an APK twice...the answer is you can't. When you build an APK it doesn't get "signed by build."

Comment: you can't sign app-debug.apk (using jarsigner) but you can sign app-release-unsigned.apk multiple times (using jarsigner). Do you know why?

Comment: When you run a debug version of your app, it is automatically signed with the system debug certificate (perhaps that's what you meant by "signed by build"), but to sign a release APK, you need to use your own certificate to manually sign it.